# Debugging map insertion?

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, insertion

I'm having an issue with inserting an entry into a Map.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Nodo
{
public:
    vector<Nodo> Relaciones;
    int Valor;
    bool Visitado;

    Nodo(int V)
    {
        Valor = V;
        Visitado = false;
    }
};

class Grafo
{
public:
    Nodo *Raiz;
    map<int, Nodo> Nodos;

    Grafo(int V)
    {
        Raiz = new Nodo(V);
        //Getting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd(v=VS.100).aspx here
        Nodos.insert(pair<int, Nodo>(V, Raiz));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a type mismatch. You're passing a `Nodo*` into the `pair` constructor while it expects a `Nodo` object.

You declare:

```
Nodo *Raiz;
```

and then you try to call:

```
pair<int, Nodo>(V, Raiz)
```

which expects an `int` and a `Nodo`. But you passed it `int` and `Nodo*`.

What you probably want is this:

```
class Grafo
{
    public:
        Nodo *Raiz;
        map<int, Nodo*> Nodos;    //  change to pointer

        Grafo(int V)
        {
            Raiz = new Nodo(V);
            //Getting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd(v=VS.100).aspx here
            Nodos.insert(pair<int, Nodo*>(V, Raiz));   // change to pointer
        }
};
```

Comment: Hmmm you made me realize that [As well as Mankarse], and adding a * in front of Raiz did the trick. what i dont seem to understand is that as far as i know, the de-reference (&) operator should of done it instead... why is this happening?

Comment: `&` is the "address-of" operator. `*` is the "dereference" operator.

Comment: `&` won't work in this case because it's still incompatible with `Nodo*` which is what `Raiz` is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Rais` is a pointer to `Nodo`, but you are trying to insert it into a map from `int` to `Nodo` (not a map from `int` to `Nodo*`).

Try:

```
class Grafo
{
    public:
        Nodo *Raiz;
        map<int, Nodo> Nodos;

        Grafo(int V)
        {
            Raiz = &*Nodos.insert(pair<int, Nodo>(V, Nodo(V))).first;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, 'new' returns a pointer to the object. In order to obtain the object itself, you would need to dereference it by using the '*' operator. That is why the map fails to work.

Additionally if you want to insert values into a map which I personally believe looks clearer is by doing

```
typedef map<int, Nodo> MyMap;
MyMap myawesomemap;
int V = 5;
Nodo* Raiz = new Raiz(5);
myawesomemap.insert(MyMap::value_type(V, (*Raiz)));
```

Comment: I reckon your solution does work and it's cleaner, i am just a little n00b when it comes to Cpp :p